# How would one filter responses from a grain?

Tags: c#, orleans

I have started looking into Orleans and was wondering if, for example, the Orleans server acted as a log server and a grain provided functionality to return a List of Log objects is there a way to do some filtering/sorting?

Essentially instead of Select * From Logs where type = 'exception' how is this done with Orleans besides getting all logs and sorting/filtering client side?

Comment: During my research I've found even the 'Select * from Logs where type = 'exception'" or indexing isn't really supported by Orleans. I was of the assumption that Orleans could be used server side between the database and the web server, but with these restrictions it appears to have a specific use cases.

Comment: Orleans is an [actor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) framework/runtime for distributed processing, not some magic ORM abstraction. Grain = Actor. Its fundamentally different from regular OOP processing and usually an Actor represents one entity that's encapsulated (i.e. Order, Customer). It can also be good used for hot-caching (getting a specific result and store that in a stateless grain/actor) to avoid too many db hits. Its good for every workload which you can easily access via a single (int, guid, string) or two keys. Hence no indexing (other than on the key and grain type)